# IBM Bluemix AJAX call fails with status of 404

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
task.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/:1
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ajax.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://task.eu-gb.mybluemix.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Answer (score 1):

What were you doing to do this?  The page `ajax.php` does not run on `api.eu-gb.bluemix.net`.  This URL is the Cloud Foundry API.  If you were trying to request your own page `ajax.php` you should reference it in your code with `/ajax.php`.